# Should i do math in Django ORM or in Python

Tags: mysql, django, aggregate

I work with Django and have big database with around 30.000 records. My job is to do some simple math with all of the records. Data in the database is related to 50 persons. I have to filter rows for each person and then to calculate the average value for each of the 10 columns. So i would have to filter the data for 50 times (because i have to calculate and present data for each of the 50 persons separately) and to do the math. I have done this task with just one line of code (that is looped over 50 times):

```
qs = Mymodel.objects.filter(person=person).values()
records[i] = qs.aggregate(Avg('question-1'),Avg('question-2'),...Avg('question-10'))
# Heavy SQL operation
```

but django debug toolbar says it takes around 6.6 seconds for this request to be done (with around 55 sql queries, which i expected).

This is only one task and i will have to do additional 7-8 similar mathematical tasks, so the whole job could easily sum up to 400 - 500 sql queries.

I am concerned about performance issues so i would like to know what would be better and faster approach - should i do the math directly in the database with row filtering and aggregate queries or it would be better to prefetch whole database table with 30.000 rows (but it is expected to grow in future with 30.000 rows per year) and to do the math in python?

Comment: How often does this need to run? Once a day? On ever page load? We have a database for a very large lute music collection, and there's a lot of munching to build page views after we do an update. But that's at most once a day, and more often once ever couple of weeks. All of the pages are heavily cached and are only cleaned out on a DBMS update. So we just don't worry about the overhead of the rebuild; it's noise.

Comment: It would have to run just a few times in a month, so it's not so important to have some lightning performances but i was asking this question mostly because of good practice i should learn now for the future, when working with bigger databases.. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about django, but I do know SQL.  I have an outline of a solution for you.

30,000 records isn't big; it's hardly a warmup.  The reason your code is slow is that you're issuing one query per person.  Your DBMS can produce multiple aggregations for *all* persons much faster using the GROUP BY feature of SQL:

```
select person, avg(question-1), avg(question-2)
from tablename
group by person
```

The important rule is that every non-aggregate in the `select` set must appear in the `group by` set.

If all your aggregates are about `person` and all come from the same table, you need only a single query.  I bet it will take longer to process the results than it will take the DBMS to produce them.

Comment: You are right, group by statement gave me exactly what i need, in less then 0.1 s which is perfect! I tried to execute exactly the same raw sql command in django (instead of using it's ORM) but unfortunately it hits the database 122 times, and i don't know why. Of course, when i execute same query directly in mysql everything is ok. Thank you for your suggestion, i just need now somehow to solve this sql duplicating..

Answer (score 0):

[Annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) could help and reduce number of SQL queries to one:

```
Person.objects.annotate(
    Avg('question-1'), Avg('question-2'), ..., Avg('question-10')
)
```